# JavaScript infinity loop in calculator

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a small calculator that allows you to input a string. So it has to recognize which sign has to be executed in first place.

My problem is that somewhere and by some reason it creates a stackoverflow. I was expecting if you could help me to find out.

The first for is to give each operator a precedence, so * is more important than +. Second loop is destinated to find  the sign into the string, so if input.indexOf(signos[i]) is lower or than 0 it jumps off the operator. if its dalse it goes in and put the number in left side and right side into two aux values and in the end it solves the sign and replace it into the string so at the end it shows you the result.

Thanks.

```
var input;
var signos = ['*', '/', '+', '-'];
var cursor = 0;
var aux1 = "";
var aux2 = "";
var auxSigno = "";
var resuelto = 0;
var encontrado = false;

function lectura(){
    input = document.getElementById("ans").value;
    console.log(input);
    for(i = 0; i < signos.length; i++){
        cursor =  input.indexOf(signos[i]);
        //console.log(cursor);
        if (cursor > -1){
            auxSigno = input.charAt(cursor);
            //console.log(auxSigno);
            for(j = 0; j < input.length; i++){
                for(k = cursor-1; comparar(k); k--){
                    aux1+=input[k];
                }

                for(l = cursor+1; comparar(l); l++){
                    aux2+=input[l];
                }


                operar();
                var cadena = aux1+auxSigno+aux2;
                var auxCadena = input.replace(cadena, resuelto);
                input = auxCadena;
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(input);
}

function comparar(caracter){
    for(m = 0; m < signos.length; m++){
        if (caracter === signos[m]){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function operar(){
    console.log(auxSigno);
    console.log(aux1);
    console.log(aux2);

    if (signos.indexOf(auxSigno) == 0){
        resuelto = parseFloat(aux1) * parseFloat(aux2);
        console.log(resuelto + " opc1");
    } else if (signos.indexOf(auxSigno) == 1) {
        resuelto = parseFloat(aux1) / parseFloat(aux2);
        console.log(resuelto + " opc2");
    } else if (signos.indexOf(auxSigno) == 2) {
        resuelto = parseFloat(aux1) + parseFloat(aux2);
        console.log(resuelto + " opc3")
    } else if (signos.indexOf(auxSigno) == 3){
        resuelto = parseFloat(aux1) - parseFloat(aux2);
        console.log(resuelto + " opc4")
    } else {
        console.log("opc no implementada");
    }
}
```

if the input is "6+6*8", the result should be "54", but it doesn't show anything, just keep doing the for.

Comment: It looks like you made a copy/paste mistake with `for(j = 0; j < input.length; i++){`. It should be `for(j = 0; j < input.length; j++){`

Comment: this is wayyy too many nested loops. you should rethink how you are approaching this problem.

Comment: If you wish to use mathjs library, solution will be one-liner i.e. math.evaluate('your-expression')